# How to get subfolder and image name from given path

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, operating-system

I want to split the path of the images in order to get the subfolder name and also the image names with their extension. I have something like this:

```
./train/00008383/20120111_095220.jpg'
```

and I want to keep only this:

```
00008383/20120111_095220.jpg'
```

I tried to use the os.path.split but all I got was either the first part
without the image name

```
os.path.split(img)[-2]
    './train/00008383'
```

or the second part with only the image name.
Do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```py
path = os.path.normpath(img).split(os.path.sep)
new_path = os.path.join(*path[-2:])
```

`path` is a list of all the directories

```
['train', '00008383', '20120111_095220.jpg']
```

Which you can join the parts you want to keep into a new path by `os.path.join(*path[-2:])`

```
'00008383/20120111_095220.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pathlib` would be the best solution since Python 3.4. It will handle paths regardless of the OS and has many useful features. Here's an example of how to achieve what you are asking.

```py
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('./train/00008383/20120111_095220.jpg')
```

You can then use the `parts` attribute to get a Tuple of all the path segments. `[-2:]` will give you the last two elements in the path, i.e. the folder and the file.

```py
partial_path = path.parts[-2:]
```

You can join your Tuple of subfolder and filename using the `str.join` method.

```py
'/'.join(partial_path)
```

The quick but unsafe way would be to simply split the string path on `/` such as:

```py
path = './train/00008383/20120111_095220.jpg'
partial_path = path.split('/')[-2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can again perform the same operation on the './train/00008383' and then add the tails of both of splits

```
path = './train/00008383/20120111_095220.jpg'
head_tail = os.path.split(path)
  
print("Head of '% s:'" % path, head_tail[0])
print("Tail of '% s:'" % path, head_tail[1])

head_tail2 = os.path.split(head_tail[0])

left = head_tail2[1] + '/' + head_tail[1]
right = head_tail2[0]

print(left)
print(right)
```